# How to restrict the width of html dropdown options list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to restrict the html drpodown option-list width by giving 
text-overflow:ellipsis like below:

```
+------------------+
| Please Select    |
+------------------+
| Long Descrip.... |
| Short Descr      |
| Long Descrip.... |
+------------------+
```

I tried this by giving

```
select option{max-width: 100px;text-overflow:ellipsis}
```

Only the dropdown width is getting reduced where as not the option width. I might be missing basic attributes to do this. But I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone suggest on this..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The width of the dropdown options panel itself is controlled by the browser chrome and as such cannot be affected by javascript.

If you need to change the appearance of the dropdown, you will need to use a plugin which transposes the `select` element to HTML elements which can be controlled, such as [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: `cannot be affected by javascript` ..or css

Comment: @downvoters  You should elaborate on downvote, not really useful here without comment...

Answer (score 5):

You could try that:

```
var $select = $('select');
$select.find('option').each(function () {
    var _tmp = $('<span/>', {
        html: this.innerHTML
    }).css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: -9999,
        left: -9999
    }).appendTo('body');
    var width = _tmp.width();
    var maxWidth = $select.width();
    while (_tmp.width() > maxWidth) {
        _tmp.text(function (index, text) {
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
    this.innerHTML = _tmp.text();
    _tmp.remove();
});
```

### --DEMO--

But Rory's answer is usually the way to go, avoiding any headhache regarding cross browser support.

Answer (score -1):

This will help you

HTML

```
<select>
    <option>asd as das das dasdasdsadasdas asd</option>
    <option>asd as das das dasdasdsadasdas asd</option>
    <option>asd as das das dasdasdsadasdas asd</option>
    <option>asd as das das dasdasdsadasdas asd</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
select{
    width:100px;
}
select option{
    width:100px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M2h6Q/4/)

Comment: -1 Because this will simply not do the trick. The options are still full width. Viewed your demo in IE, FF and Chrome with the same result.

Comment: Yes.this will only in FF. :(